# Can't post onto the activity stream of a Facebook page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, koala-gem

I am using the Koala gem. I am trying to post something to a Facebook page, which I have authentication to.

```
client = Koala::Facebook::API.new(authentication.token)
client.put_object(authentication.uid, 'og_app_name:post', { :something => link })
```

This works if I am posting to an individual profile. But posting to a Facebook page, does nothing. No error is reported. The same behavior is also evident when posting from SoundCloud.

I don't know if this is because Facebook recently introduced "timeline" to their pages. Possibly a bug somewhere?

Anyone having the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to post Open Graph actions on behalf of a page?
That functionality doesn't exist, only users can post actions